# what is a good mockwebserver for angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, mocking

I am looking for a module that can mock a httpbackend service when the APIendpoint is not ready yet. I did a quick search and found stubby. What other options are available?

Comment: Did you find something useful that you would like to share in the benefits of other user?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using SynthJs.Source and reference you'll find here:Reference
   [SynthJs](https://www.synthjs.com/)
2. Angular Firebase is another method to mock web server.Reference:[Angular Firebase Quick Start](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your stub data services out from the application then you can give a try to [stubby-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stubby-db). It requires almost no coding knowledge and can be set up in few minutes. It allows you to make dynamic response, gzip compressed response, https connection, and so many other things with minimum effort.